# Nginx rewrite rule with proxy pass

Tags: nginx, rewrite

I'm trying to implement nginx rewrite rules for the following situation

Request:

```
http://192.168.64.76/Shep.ElicenseWeb/Public/OutputDocuments.ashx?uinz=12009718&iinbin=860610350635
```

Should be redirected to:

```
http://localhost:82/Public/OutputDocuments.ashx?uinz=12009718&iinbin=860610350635
```

I tried this with no luck:

```
location /Shep.ElicenseWeb/ {
    rewrite ^/Shep.ElicenseWeb/ /$1 last;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:82;
}
```

What is the correct way to perform such a rewrite for nginx ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rewrite statement is wrong.

The `$1` on the right refers to a group (indicated by parentheses) in the matching section.

Try:

```
rewrite ^/Shep.ElicenseWeb/(.*) /$1 break;
```

Comment: Using `rewrite` for this task is [cumbersome and ineffective way](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass).

Answer (score 1):

```
location /Shep.ElicenseWeb/ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:82/;
}
```

You do not need `rewrite` at all. Just a `/` in the end of `proxy_pass`.

Please, read the docs: http://nginx.org/r/proxy_pass